# Can I include covariates in a one-way repeated measures ANOVA? (ANCOVA?) What do results tell me?

Tags: r, anova, rstatix, covariant, ancova

I want to test the effect of a suicide prevention film on help-seeking. I have help-seeking intentions as an outcome variable and measured this variable at three time points (pre, post, follow-up) in 50 participants. To analyse the data I would conduct a one-way repeated measures ANOVA and compare mean differences between the three time points.
However, in the pre condition I also assessed depressionscore, indentification with male gender (cses) and identification with the protagonist. Now I would like to consider these variables in the comparison of the means. Since my sample is small I don't want to use dichotomized factor variables and conduct a mixed ANOVA. So I would prefer to include the three variables as covariates. However, I have searched a lot of sources, and did not find valid information on Wether this can be done. Since usual ANCOVA models are applied in situations with additional treatment factors, which I don't have. So checking for assumptions is based on comparing treatment groups. Moreover I have doubts on what the analysis would tell me?

I used the r rstatix package in r. Here is the code:

```
res.aov <- anova_test(
  data = data_csv, dv = help_seeking_privat, wid = ID,
  within = time, covariate = c(suicidalityscore, cses, identification)
)
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

The results I get are the following:

```
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

                 Effect  DFn   DFd         F     p p<.05      ges
1      suicidalityscore 1.00 35.00 3.950e-06 0.998       9.36e-08
2                  cses 1.00 35.00 5.470e-01 0.464       1.30e-02
3        identification 1.00 35.00 2.806e+00 0.103       6.20e-02
4                  time 1.56 54.55 4.351e+00 0.026     * 2.10e-02
5 suicidalityscore:time 1.56 54.55 5.480e-01 0.538       3.00e-03
6             cses:time 1.56 54.55 2.820e-01 0.700       1.00e-03
7   identification:time 1.56 54.55 3.200e-02 0.940       1.56e-04
```

I would conclude that there is a significant effect of time and proceede with pairwise t.tests for post hoc analysis. However the covariates did not have significant effects. did I include them properly? how do I interpret the results of the covariates? And how do I check assumptions for covariates in this model? I checked anova assumptions, but nothing else, as if the covariates did not exist in my model.

I would appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Is this a coding problem? It sounds more like a question around statistics and inference from your fitted model. You'll likely get better help posting on CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/